# Como removo parte do nome de todos os arquivos em uma pasta via CMD/Powershell

Tags: windows, shell-script, powershell, sistema-de-arquivos

- Preciso padronizar o nome de todos os arquivos de uma pasta, considerando que os arquivos já tem um padrão no início de seu nome até o 8º caractere, sendo necessário apenas demover tudo na sequência.
  Exemplo: atualmente "A200T011 - Fulano de tal.docx" --> como deve ficar "A200T011.docx".
- Condições: usar script para rodar no Windows ou  Windows Server, podendo ou não ser aplicado em um arquivo .bat

Eu já escrevi um script que apaga os caracteres que não quero, porém fica muito custoso listar todos os caracteres que devem ser apagados, seria mais interessante fazer o contrário, informando um conjunto de caracteres (poucos) e apagar tudo que não for igual a isso. Segue meu script:

`get-childitem | foreach {rename-item $_ $_.Name.Replace("E","")}`

O script acima substitui a letra 'E' por vazio.

Comment: No caso voce quer remover todos os caracertes dos arquivos menos os primeiros 8 + a extenção.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Da pra fazer com a função `Substring` para buscar parte do nome do arquivo e unir com a extensão dele.

Veja:

```
Get-ChildItem * | % { Rename-Item $_ ($_.Name.Substring(0,8) + $_.Extension) }
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente